# Describe $\operatorname{Gal}_F(f)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

Describe $\operatorname{Gal}_F(f)$ up to isomorphism for $f=x^4 - 1$

a) $F = \mathbb{Q}$

b) $F = \mathbb{F}_5$

c) $F = \mathbb{F}_{2017}$

I don't know if I am approaching this the right way. I know that f has roots $-1, 1, -i, i$ so in the case of $F = \mathbb{Q}$ the splitting field would be $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ so the Galois extension is just $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ since $\mathbb{Q}$ has characteristic 0 and is therefore separable.  In the case of $\mathbb{F}_5$, the characteristic is nonzero so I don't know what to do.  I guess we should use the substitution of $x \rightarrow cx + d, cd \in F$ since its the only thing I see in my notes that doesn't require a field of chracteristic 0 or $f$ to be a quadratic or cubic polynomial, but I don't see how

Comment: You're along the right lines for a), can you think what possible automorphisms there could be? How many can you have? For b), can you think of some roots, possibly (or not) in a splitting field?

Comment: For a?  I think 2 because you have the identity and the map that sends to the negative

Comment: Is sending to the negative an automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ that fixes $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: For b, the roots are the same? -1 and 1 are in the field and again $-i, i$ are not.  So $\mathbb{F}_5(i)$ would be a splitting field and if its separable I'm done?

Comment: @B.Mehta I suppose not

Comment: Identity does count though. You're along the right lines again

Comment: Is there just one for a?  Also I'm not sure if you saw, but I edited my comment above about b. Does $\mathbb{F}_5(i)$ work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77065/discussion-between-b-mehta-and-user558377).

Comment: The polynomial factors as $f(x)=(x^{2}+1)(x+1)(x-1)$ in each of these fields. So you should ask if $x^{2}+1$ factors in $\mathbb{Q}$ $\mathbb{F}_{5}$ or $\mathbb{F}_{2017}$. It obviously doesn't in $\mathbb{Q}$, as you pointed out. So the Galois group is nontrivial. But, you should be able to show $f(x)$ splits into linear factors over $\mathbb{F}_{5}$. In other words ``$\mathbb{F}_{5}$ already contains $i$" - As for 2017.  I have not checked :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summarising what was discussed in chat:

1. Two of the roots of $f$ are in $\mathbb{Q}$.
2. The splitting field of $f$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, since $i$ and $-i$ solve $f$, and this is all the roots.
3. The automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ fixing $\mathbb{Q}$ are the identity and complex conjugation.
4. We have $[\mathbb{Q}(i):Q]=2$, so the size of the Galois group is at most $2$, so we can find the Galois group...
5. For $\mathbb{F}_5$, $2$ and $3$ solve $f$, as well as $1$ and $4$, so $f$ splits over $\mathbb{F}_5$.
6. So the splitting field is the base field, and we can find the Galois group.

As discussed in the comments below and in chat, $x^2 + 1$ splits over $\mathbb{F}_p$ for a prime $p$ if and only if $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$.

Comment: Do you know a nice theorem we can appeal to in order to show $f(x)$ splits in $\mathbb{F}_{2017}$?

Comment: Hint: the special case of quadratic reciprocity for $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)$.

Comment: It does not get much nicer than quadratic reciprocity!